# Not Loading View in Spring MVC

Tags: spring-mvc

I'm beginner!!! I have been experimenting with Java Servlets for web applications, and I was able to successfully invoke a Servlet and load a .jsp page. However, when I moved on to using Spring MVC, I encountered an issue where my servlet controller class is being called, but the view is not being loaded, error Whitelabel Error Page status 404.

The problem lies in the file **viewresolver-dispatcher-servlet.xml**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qgJPi.png)

File **web.xml**:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vxYh8.png)

Controller:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MqPeh.png)

Project setup:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1jDNN.png)

But when I set in **application.properties** as follows, views display normally:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TYJI4.png)